# "Sketching" a graph

Tags: word-choice, terminology, connotation, mathematics

While this is in the context of a math problem, the question refers to the connotations and meaning of the word "sketch", so I imagine it fits this site, at least somewhat.

If one asks another to "sketch" a graph (with no further information), is it implied that one would want said graph to be quantitatively exact, or is the implication that a quicker, more free-form graph would be acceptable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Maths, sketching a graph is opposed to plotting a graph.

When a graph is plotted graph paper is used, many points are calculated, often at regular intervals, and the shape of the curve is clearly shown when those points are marked on the graph paper.

When a graph is sketched graph paper is not used and points on the axes are marked by eye instead of being measured. A few points will probably be calculated and marked on the graph, and the curve will be drawn freehand. Sometimes the axis scales are not drawn, but the values where the curve crosses the axes are written in.

Comment: *"When a graph is sketched graph paper is not used"* is a bit to strong.  It's not *required* but it's perfectly reasonable to sketch a graph on graph paper if that's what you've got to hand. For example some lab books have alternate lined and graph pages, and the graph pages are used for a lot of  drawn/plotted work.

Comment: @ChrisH, if I am using graph paper I find myself plotting the important points instead of locating them by eye. The result is a bit more accurate than a sketch graph would be.

Comment: @Peter: In scenarios where a sketched graph is sufficient, which inherently means you don't need the precision from plotting it accurately, you don't suddenly lose the value of said sketched graph just because it's on graph paper. What you're saying is essentially that you'd only ever sketch a graph if you did not have graph paper on hand. Which is fine, but not something that you can expect from a general definition of what a sketched graph is.

Answer (score 14):

Back in college, when I was a math major, "curve sketching" was a unit in calculus class. After you'd learned some derivative tricks, which aren't hard, you can solve for zeroes and inflection points of an equation (you **do** have to have an equation to sketch the curve of -- I'm not talking about drawing curves through dot collections in statistics), and once you know them you can tell that the curve goes UP *here*, and DOWN *here*, and has a sharp point *here*.

It was necessary at the time (1960) because incoming college freshmen had insufficient knowledge of analytic geometry. They still do, but methods have changed.

Answer (score 8):

"Sketch" typically implies a more "free-form" activity.

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sketch) describes it as a "rough drawing"

However, your specific example of sketching a graph could depend on context. I'm going to assume this is for some kind of class, so I'll use those kinds of examples. If a question asks you to "sketch" a graph, it probably just wants you to get the shape right. For example, making sure you recognize the data/equation as forming a normal distribution and not a binomial one, or a parabola and not a hyperbola, or a sine wave and not a cosine wave. You should probably check with whomever gave you the question though.

Comment: One generally draws a graph. I would never use the word sketch here  unless that was on a napkin....

Comment: Yes to this answer... and MW doesn't just say a rough drawing, but a rough drawing *representing the chief features*.  In other words it serves to highlight the notable keys, just as a sketch of a building or invention might.  As such, it's often not just the shape, but also the labeling of key points (if it's something important to convey/something a student is expected to know). If the vertex is (3, -8), it isn't about carefully measuring that out, but about showing a very rough idea of it (e.g. in the right quadrant), and then labeling the point to clarify that's what is meant to be shown.

Comment: @Lambie we sketch graphs all the time when discussing data in work (physics, especially with students where you want to show them but not do it for them. ) - and we use the term sketch when we do so.  Quite often we'll have a software plot on screen, and on paper or a whiteboard we'll outline the shape and annotate the key features and tasks for the next steps in presentation/analysis.

Comment: Right, I believe you, no problem. Am not a math person.

Answer (score 7):

Graph sketching, as the term is used in a British mathematical context, implies **producing a drawing by considering the nature of the function rather than by plotting points**. A typical sketch would display:

- The *y*-intercept (point where the graph crosses the *y*-axis) calculated and shown in the correct part of the axis (i.e. the positive part, origin or negative part).
- Any roots/*x*-intercepts shown in the correct part of the axis, and possibly labelled.
- Turning points (points where the gradient/slope is zero) in the correct quadrants, and possibly labelled.
- Any asymptotes (a feature where the graph approaches, but does not touch, a line or curve) indicated, possibly with the asymptote shown as a dashed line or similar.
- The correct general shape, in terms of features like concavity (whether the graph curves upwards or downwards), discontinuities, cusps, sharp angles etc.

**Features of the sketch should be in the correct quadrants**, and **their relative positions should have the correct order** (e.g. if there is a feature at (-3,2) and a feature at (4,8) then the second should be vertically higher than the first), but there is **no expectation of a consistent scale** (the second does not need to be four times further away from the *x*-axis), and indeed in general the preference is to emphasise legibility over scale.

Depending on context, a graph sketch might be done very roughly (free-hand axes and a quick drawing) or more carefully (axes drawn with a ruler and more time spent on the shape of the curve) but **the features should generally be identified by considering the type of equation and using algebraic methods (solving equations, differentiation, limits) rather than calculation of points**.

If one were producing lecture notes or a teaching document, you might even generate a 'sketch' using software, potentially by plotting a different graph that has the desired features and changing the labels.

Comment: You see it a British then? Maybe I do too, but I haven;t spend enough time anywhere else to be sure.  The approach is similar in physics, though often with measured key data points rather than calculations - or both, comparing theory to expt.

Comment: @ChrisH My experience is British, so I didn't want to confidently state it was universal (especially with someone commenting they'd never heard it). It's a standard term in British maths education and practice.